# "lvalue required" error when trying to increment array

Tags: c, arrays, lvalue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

Suppose I have a char array say arr and arr will represent the address of first element so arr++ should be perfectly legal then why compiler says 'lvalue required'.

Also if I do:
arr=arr+1 then why it is invalid conversion. I am just increasing pointer by one. Compiler tells that on LHS the operand type is char[4] but on RHS it is char *.

```
main()
{
char arr[]={'a','b','c','d'};
for(;arr!=arr+4;arr++) //lvalue required 
printf("%c",*arr);
}
```

Comment: post your code what you've tried so far

Comment: "arr will represent the address of first element" No, it will represent an array. That array may be implicitly converted to a pointer, which will have the same value as `&arr[0]`, but that doesn't make it a pointer.

Answer (score 6):

An array name is not a variable that can be assigned to.  If you want to modify it, you should use a pointer variable:

```
char *arr_ptr = arr;
```

You can then do `arr_ptr++` and `arr_ptr = arr_ptr+1`;

Answer (score 2):

Arrays aren't pointers. `arr` does not represent an address.

Comment: `arr` does represent of fist element address.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan No, it doesn't (and that was barely coherent).

Comment: What I mean `arr` contains fist element's address..Although I am not down-voter!

Comment: `arr` doesn't contain an address.

Answer (score 2):

An array name, or any expression of array type, is implicitly converted to a pointer to the array's first element *unless* it's either:

- The operand of a unary `&` (address-of) expression (which yields the address of the whole array, not of its first element -- same memory address, different type); or
- The operand of a `sizeof` operator (`sizeof arr` yields the size of the array, not the size of a pointer); or
- The operand of an `_Alignof` operator (`_Alignof arr` yields the alignment of the array, not the alignment of a pointer); or
- A string literal in an initializer that's used to initialize an arrary object.

`_Alignof` is new in C2011.

(The conversion is often referred to as a "decaying".)

None of these apply here, so `arr++` *tries* to increment a pointer object. The problem is, there is no pointer *object*, just a pointer *value*. `arr`, after it decays to a pointer value, is not an lvalue, which means it cannot appear on the left side of an assignment or as the operand of `++`.

Similarly, given:

```
int x;
```

the expression `x` is an lvalue, so you can write `x = 42;` -- but the expression `(x + 1)` is not an lvalue, so you can't write `(x + 1) = 42;`.  You can assign to `x` because it refers to an *object*.  `(x+1)` doesn't refer to an object, so there's nothing to assign to.  `arr`, after it decays, doesn't refer to an object either (you have an array object, but there's no pointer object).

(Your use of `arr != arr + 4` should have been a clue; that can never be true.)

Rather than this:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
for (; arr != arr + 4; arr++) {
    printf("%c", *arr);
}
```

you can write this:

```
char arr[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char *ptr;
for (ptr = arr; ptr != arr + 4; ptr++) {
    printf("%c", &ptr);
}
```

Incidentally, at the top of your program, you should change this:

```
main()
```

to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
```

Also, run, do not walk, to the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com) and read section 6, "Arrays and pointers".