# assigning strings to a variable

Tags: c, arrays, string

I want to know why the first code works but the second one doesn't.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char *last, *first, *middle;
    char pres[20] = "Adams, John Quincy";
    char pres_copy[20];
    strcpy(pres_copy, pres);

    last = strtok(pres_copy, ", ");
    printf("%s", last);

    first = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    printf("%s", first);

    middle = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    printf("%s", middle);

}
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char last[20], first[20], middle[20];
    char pres[20] = "Adams, John Quincy";
    char pres_copy[20];
    strcpy(pres_copy, pres);

    last = strtok(pres_copy, ", ");
    printf("%s", last);

    first = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    printf("%s", first);

    middle = strtok(NULL, ", ");
    printf("%s", middle);

}
```

I thought array names were the same as pointers.
But the compiler is making a distinction, since it told me type `'char [20]'` and type `'char *'` was incompatible.

How and why are the two data types different?

Comment: Exactly. Arrays have bounds while pointers don't.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers. That's all.

Comment: Check this link too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667191/lvalue-required-error-when-trying-to-increment-array

Answer (score 2):

An array is not a pointer. You're trying to assign a pointer to an array. See [this C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html) entry about arrays and pointers.

Answer (score 0):

'char [20]' and type 'char *' are incompatible.`char *` can hold a pointer to `char` means it can store address of `char` not simple `char`.`char [20]` is an array of 20 character(not address of characters).

Just using the name of array makes it pointer to its first element.So passing array name as argument does not mean passing of whole array.It is just pointer to first element.

`strtok` returns a `char *` so expecting a `char *` as lvalue of assignment.